# JOSM plugin won't work (PicLayer)

Tags: openstreetmap

I have been trying to `georeference` the floor plan of my home university using `Java OpenStreetMap` (JOSM). I have been following the guide from their website (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IndoorOSM) until i got stuck on the PicLayer plugin part.

The plugin when downloaded (version 29809) will never appear in my Menu bar, not even after couple of restarts of my computer AND even on a fresh virtual machine, with fresh java `JRE` the plugin just won't appear in the menu.

I understand that this isn't the perfect place for posting such a problem, but unfortunately when visiting `JOSM` forums i got banged with this message "This forum is not accepting new registrations."

Comment: There is an official bug tracker for JOSM: http://josm.openstreetmap.de/newticket. And with josm-tested (6115) the pic layer plugin seems to work here. I have both icons in the sidebar after clicking at the two arrows for a drop-down menu, and I have pic layer options in the tool bar under *Imagery*.

Comment: Thanks for the bug tracker website provided, since I can't see any new icons within my editor and the Imagery drop down won't show any options for PicLayer i will head and create the new ticket.

Comment: Try deleting the plugin and installing it again. Or maybe your whole local JOSM directory.

Comment: I did try deleting the entire JOSM directory, however the plugin remains installed even after fresh installation of JOSM. Would you by any chance know how to uninstall those plugins or at least the directory where they reside?

Comment: I got to find out that in Windows 7 & Vista the plugins reside in directory C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JOSM\plugins. I have installed some other random plugin called 'editGpx' which has successfully been shown in my editor, however after manually deleting PicLayer and installing it back again it still won't appear. I guess I will wait for the ticket response from JOSM staff about this issue, thanks anyway :)

Comment: That's strange because it works here. Although on Linux but this shouldn't make a difference because the JOSM jar is the same and other plugins seem to work for you.

Comment: Question is about the OSM Editor software.

Answer (score 1):

I already replied to the [JOSM ticket](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/9086#comment:9) but also give the answer here.

The plugin was not correctly installed. To install a plugin, the recommended way is to download and install it directly from JOSM preferences (F12).

If the plugin jar is manually downloaded, it must be manually enabled in JOSM preferences by checking its tickbox in plugins tab:

[image: screenshot]